# Download refreshed html data?

Tags: java, html, refresh, stock

I'm trying to download html data from an url in java.  Here is my code:

```
url = new URL("https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=QQQ" + addToHTML[addHTMLCount]);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

html = "";
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    html = html + inputLine;            
}
```

But the second time I get the html data it is the same as the first, this goes on for hours!  The same code didn't used to do this?  Should I be refreshing something?

Comment: What do you expect in second time?

Comment: The updated html.  In this example the price of the stock should be different.